# best way to avoid url tampering in an mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

I'm building a web app hosted in azure and using azure active directory.  I have 2 types of user

standard & admin

admin users can create custom menus to allow standard users access to specific areas of the site. So when a standard user logs in, they will only see the menu items that have been created specifically for them.  This works ok but how do I stop a user just pasting in a URL which points to areas of the site they don't have access to ? Ive protected the controllers with filter and authorise attributes to stop them typing different parameter values but this doesnt stop them pasting in a complete url to an area not configured on the main menu.

Ive created a table which holds menu items along with controller and action names, so for instance

menu item customers would have a customer controller and index action stored with it and I can check that way.  But its getting messy, there could be edit actions, delete actions, etc, etc and they could just paste a url in the nav bar.

Is there some generic way to do this ?

Comment: You can't. You need to use access control to prevent users from seeing pages they shouldn't.  And when I say "access control", I mean you have to know who the user is, and what urls they are allowed to see, and when they make a request, you have to check the request against this list of urls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access control in a ASP.MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114256/access-control-in-a-asp-mvc-application)

Comment: If you have applied Roles to your `[Authorize]` attribute then standard users will not be able to access methods marked with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`

Comment: standard users are allowed access to the system, admin users can configure a set of menu items, which would be specific to each user.  The user wont se any areas they aren't given access to., but it wouldn't stop them typing in the full url in the address bar, so I'm guessing ill have to have a list of allowable urls for each user ?

Comment: @proteus - No. Access control in MVC is not supposed to be done with URLs because it is quite easy to circumvent this type of security (intentionally or accidentally) by creating an alternate route to get to the same action. So, you should use the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` attribute on the action itself which will prevent unauthorized users from reaching the action method (even if they know a valid URL to get to it).